# how to break out of mainloop() without closing the gui

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a simple python GUI that fills in a grid based on the values in an array, and I want this simple GUI to sit on screen while other functions run. The time for these other functions is indeterminate, so I can't simply call them at some regular interval using after(time, function)

```
def go(self):
    """
    Start the main GUI loop
    :return:
    """
    mainloop()
```

The mainloop starts in the go function, and I want to know if it is possible to either break out of mainloop without closing the window or to draw the GUI without calling mainloop at all?

I know I can do

```
after(time, function)
```

but I'm at a loss as to what to call to kill the mainloop while keeping the GUI on-screen.

Comment: If you stop the mainloop the GUI will be unresponsive. The mainloop is what powers the moving, resizing, reacting to input etc. I highly doubt that's what you want.

Comment: That's exactly what I want, the GUI just needs to draw in the grid and then sit there doing exactly nothing while other functions run in the background until they're complete.

Comment: No you don't understand. Stopping the mainloop will cause your OS to pop up the "this program has become unresponsive" box and stop your whole program. What you want is to use the `threading` module to run your functions simultaneously with the mainloop.

Comment: Is it possible to get the GUI to draw without ever starting the mainloop? I don't need any interactivity in the GUI once it has filled in the grid.

Comment: Yes it's possible but I guarantee it's not what you want.

Comment: @Novel If the mainloop is not being used or is stopped would that not end the program thus removing the GUI as well?

Comment: @Mike-SMT Normally, yes, but we can prevent that if we want to. Or in this case don't start the mainloop at all and just update the GUI manually. But it won't work like OP is hoping.

Comment: @Novel AH ya I remember seeing a post where someone created a function that updated the loop manually rather than with `mainloop`. I have yet to see where that would be useful and also do not believe it is what the OP needs here.

Comment: You can get it to draw, but without `mainloop` it won't be able to redraw if, for example, it's resized.

Comment: @Mike: what you say is technically incorrect. It's possible to stop and later restart `mainloop`.

Comment: @BryanOakley Ya after Novel answered my question I can see how my statement was not accurate.

Comment: @Novel The specific sequence of events I want to happen are as follows: 1) GUI draws in the grid 2) other functions run until they complete 3) GUI closes at the end of the other functions. 

I don't need to worry about resizing the window, redrawing any part of the GUI, or any other form of interactivity on the GUI. I just need the window to sit on the screen until the program finishes.

Comment: Boy you are stubborn ... I don't know what else I can tell you ... I have lots of experience with this and I know that you need to use a thread. Killing the mainloop will not work like you think it will. If you show us a [mcve] I'll write it both ways for you and let you try them both.

Comment: I'm not trying to be stubborn, I'm just very new to python. Your first reply says that "The mainloop is what powers the moving, resizing, reacting to input etc." and that killing it isn't what I want, but there is no window moving/resizing/user input to deal with. I actually do just want the window to sit still on the screen until the program finishes running and then close, and I'm having trouble understanding why I need to have this loop running and doing nothing instead of just killing it and letting the window sit there.

Comment: It's not just user input; also handling requests from the OS. Gimme a [mcve] and I'll let you see for yourself what it handles. Or lets approach this another way: Using a thread is extremely simple and the standard method of doing this, and as a bonus you don't lock up your GUI window. What do you have against threading?

Comment: @Novel: you're being a bit impolite. It's clear from the question that the poster does _not_ need to use threads. They clearly state they do not want the GUI to be responsive while the rest of the program runs. While unusual, I think you're being a bit rude. It's ok to explain the ramifications of such a choice but you don't need to call them stubborn.

Answer (score 0):

Use the threading module to run your function alongside the mainloop:

```
from threading import Thread

def go(self):
    t = Thread(target=function)
    t.start() # start the thread in the background
    mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply put: you can't, or at least it's not what you want to do. I would recommend restructuring you code to put it in the main loop (like making tkinter a class and calling the functions in your init function). If you post your whole code I can help you with it.

Comment: What I want is for the GUI to sit on the screen dumb as a rock with no interactivity (i.e. no need to resize or redraw anything) I don't need to worry about listeners or user input once the grid is finished drawing.

Comment: Yah so it would be better to incorporate your function in the TK class like I said and it will work (sit there doing nothing)

Answer (score 0):

> The mainloop starts in the go function, and I want to know if it is possible to either break out of mainloop without closing the window or to draw the GUI without calling mainloop at all?

It sounds like you have a very unique need. To give you a literal answer, yes, it's possible to break out of mainloop without closing the window. You can call `quit` on the root window to cause `mainloop` to exit. You can restart `mainloop`, or call the `update` method on the root window to process events.

This is not typically how a GUI should work, but if you're absolutely certain that you don't need the window to update while the program is running, you can certainly do that if you wish.